# How to display/get the entire list of objects.Console.log() displays only first object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting message on console. "This value was evaluated on first expanding. The value may have changed since then."
Is there a way I can collect all objects in list in JavaScript.

**Output in Console**

```
{
"#": {
    "id": "#",
    "parent": null,
    "parents": [],
    "children": [],
    "children_d": [],
    "state": {
        "loaded": false,
        "failed": false,
        "loading": true
    },
    "type": "#"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am introducing a global variable and pushing the data to the global variable,
Now I can access the global variable externally.

```
    [
[
    "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.55c98007-64e8-4ab9-b726-e08e222a68d1/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:f_I5bPF4QLyg9aVFxmEFkQ",
    "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.55c98007-64e8-4ab9-b726-e08e222a68d1/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:lIf5I0UnRY2og_jCPwrjaQ",
    "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.55c98007-64e8-4ab9-b726-e08e222a68d1/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:pQ_8nGRNQxCnUYAhTLNEyw",
    "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.55c98007-64e8-4ab9-b726-e08e222a68d1/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:_QA5IS30Tc64oagCPLL8vQ",
```

]
]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).